# iOS - handle arabic / right to left languages in push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, arabic

When I send a push notification with the message being

```
يامن الرفاعي did X
```

It shows up on the device as

```
did X يامن الرفاعي
```

But if I were to send

```
hey يامن الرفاعي did X
```

It will show up as the original message

Any idea of how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they go with the language that you used for the first word , that's why when you started by hey , they recognized that you are using a left to right language , but when you start by Arabic , it will start from the right to left

Comment: That looks right. Too bad we can't send a parameter to set this. Thanks